# process 100K of image files with bash

Tags: bash, shell, hashtable

here is the script to optimize jpg images: https://github.com/kormoc/imgopt/blob/master/imgopt

There is a CMS with image files (not mine).
I assume there is a complicated structure of subdirectories and script just recursively find all img files in given folder.
The question is how to mark already processed files so with next run
script won't touch them and just skip?
I dont know when the guys would like to add new files to it and process it. Also I think renaming is not a good choice either.

I was thinking about hash-table or associative array which will be filled from txt file during
start. But is it ok to have 100K of items array in bash? Seems complicated for a script.

Any other ideas about optimization are also welcome.

Comment: put them in a new folder called `processed`?

Comment: give them a unique prefix / suffix?

Comment: use a Makefile? it all depends on your exact scenario.

Comment: look at their modification time, or use some naming convention. Or move processed files to a different directory.

Comment: What are your requirements in terms of 'file can/cannot move', 'programs can/cannot crash'.  Does the command being executed work on a single file at a time, or on groups of files?  Parallelism?  Is there a problem if a file is processed twice?  Gut feel: 100K items in a Bash array will 'work', but will not necessarily work fast. OTOH, the alternatives may be worse.  But a lot depends on the processing and resiliency requirements.

Comment: Its like there is a CMS with image files (not mine). And I dont know when the guys would like to add new files to it and process it. Also I assume there is a complicated structure of subdirectories and script just recursively find all img files in given folder. So I think renaming is not a good choice either.

Comment: Add that information to the question.  Does a file ever change content without changing name?  What, roughly, is the existing script doing -- what is the high-level goal of running the program on all 100K files?  Do you have to spot files that should be present but are missing?  Do you have to spot files that are present but weren't previously known to be present?  How long does it take to process each file? That's a lot of files; you can probably afford to spend time thinking about how to process them efficiently.

Comment: file was optimized with script. a month has passed. script is running again. file doesn't need to be processed. how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is just output a file with a similar name per processed image file.

For example `image1.jpg` after being processed would have an empty file with a similar name e.g. `.image1.jpg.processed`.

Then when your script runs it just checks if the for the current image: `NAME.EXT` if a file `.NAME.EXT.processed` exists. If the file doesn't exist then you know it needs to be processed. No memory issues and no hashtable needed granted you will have 100K of empty extra files.

Comment: sounds great. simple and elegant solution. I will try this way and hope everyone will be happy ;) Thanks.